# Pyqt5 changing qpushbutton stylesheet when hovering over it

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qtstylesheets, qpushbutton

So I'm making an application using pyqt5 and what I'm trying to do is make a qpushbutton of a custom style sheet that changes color when your mouse hovers over it. I searched it up and found that in python the following code works to change the hovering settings:

```
button.setStyleSheet("QPushButton::hover"
                     "{"
                     "background-color : lightgreen;"
                     "}")
```

and when I tested it out, it worked, but then it removed my custom stylesheet.

```
button.setStyleSheet("background-color: #2B5DD1; color: #FFFFFF ; border-style: outset; 
padding: 2px ; font: bold 20px ; border-width: 6px ; border-radius: 10px ; border-color: #2752B8;")
```

was my original code with just my style sheet which worked and then when I tried combining the two as follows:

```
to_meetings.setStyleSheet("background-color: #2B5DD1; color: #FFFFFF ; border-style: outset; padding: 2px ; font: bold 20px ; border-width: 6px ; border-radius: 10px ; border-color: #2752B8;"
                          "QPushButton::hover"
                          "{"
                          "background-color: #112452;"
                          "}")
```

It ran just fine, but didn't show the hover settings and instead just showed my custom stylesheet. Any idea on how to incorporate a custom stylesheet as well as hover settings?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just as you defined the QPushButton style with the `hover` pseudo-state, you can define it for the regular state.

```
QPushButton {
    background-color: #2B5DD1;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    border-style: outset;
    padding: 2px;
    font: bold 20px;
    border-width: 6px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    border-color: #2752B8;
}
QPushButton:hover {
    background-color: lightgreen;
}
```

[See customizing QPushButton examples in Qt docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-examples.html#customizing-qpushbutton)